# ASP.NET core data could not bind to dto from request body

Tags: asp.net-core

Have problem with Model binding in ASP.NET core, I am using "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1"

This is my api method

```
[Route("attach/{buildingId}")]
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> AttachToBuilding([FromRoute]Guid buildingId,[FromBody] AttachmentDto dto)
```

AttachmentDto dto is always equals null

This is dto

```
public class AttachmentDto
    {
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UniqueDeviceId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int ApartmentNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int AgreementNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int FloorNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

This is data I send to api in the body request

```
  {
      "firstName": "Artem",
      "lastName": "Lys",
      "middleName": "Викторович",
      "phone": "93840958093",
      "uniqueDeviceId": "879987",
      "apartmentNumber": "2",
      "agreementNumber": "3аываыва4545",
      "floorNumber": "5"
    }
```

Comment: Show your `AttachToBuilding` view and `AttachmentDto` model

Comment: `firstName` !=  `FirstName` - Use the same name like in model

Comment: I have tried, it did not help

Comment: Add all in `dto` (json) and will work

Comment: Are you sending with the content-type as JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I have had many problems with asp.net core for passing parameters, I have managed to solve this way.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string Atualizar([Bind("Id,Descricao,Conclusao")] Exame exame)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Request

```
$http({
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        method: "POST",
        url: URL_API + 'Exames/Atualizar,
        data: $.param(exame),
    }).then(function(response) {
        ...
    });
```

this work for me.

The secret to working in my case was to convert the json object into **$.param(exame)**